# Checking for line separator issue git?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, bitbucket, phpstorm, core.autocrlf

I'm using **PhpStorm** and I did some work locally which I want to push to repo but I'm seeing this message and `commit + push` isn't working!

When I select files and hit **commit** or **commit & push** I get `Checking for Git Username` 
and then
 `Checking for line separator issue git`

I searched for some answers and found this command:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

I set it to true and tried to commit but the message ( *Checking for line separator issue git* ) is there. Even if I set it to false still the same message is showing!

**Second try:**

I added `* text=auto` in `.gitignore` file but still the message is showing.

And finally I tried the below commands but all in vain:

```
$ git config core.eol lf
$ git config core.autocrlf input
```

**Note:** I was facing the same issue previously but when I ran this command `git config --global core.autocrlf true` everything started working smoothly. But this time it isn't working.

Comment: Since there're no mentions of this issue over the internet, probably it makes sense to submit the [IDE log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files) within a support ticket: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us

Comment: @EugeneMorozov this is a well known issue but the solutions are not working! Should I delete this question and submit it in IDE logs?

Comment: It makes sense to keep the question, and once you get the answer from support, post it here. Personally, I am a PhpStorm support engineer, but we have a separate person handling VCS cases, that's why I can't help at once here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research I just found these two solutions:

1) Copy the files where you have made changes and pull a new fresh repo and make changes in there and push it to repo

2) Manually from Terminal add the files to git, commit it and manually run `git push` and your files will be pushed to repository successfully!

**Second method proper steps:**

Let say you have made changes in `a.php` and `b.php` or whatever files

Open your terminal and add it to git like `git add a.php` and `git add b.php`

Now commit your added files by typing `git commit -m "Your message"`

and finally `git push` that's it!

**Note**: While adding files to git you might require the full path of your file

e.g `git add D:\xampp\htdocs\project.com\apps\admin\modules\test\actions\test.class.php`

Answer (score 0):

You just remove this check which under these two menus
[Remove this check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngH5E.png)

[under these two menus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xWpS.png)